# android.widget.imagebutton cannot be cast to android.widget.button Message

Tags: android, button, compiler-errors, android-activity, classcastexception

Hi I am getting this message android.widget.imagebutton cannot be cast to android.widget.button (See attachment pic for logcat error) which I don't understand why? because my code seems to be right.

Code:

```
ImageButton Calendar = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.Calendar);
Calendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent OpenCalendarbtn = new Intent (Menu.this, DisplayCalendar.class);
        startActivity (OpenCalendarbtn);
    }
});
```

[image]

Complete Layout xml file:

`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Read"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Write"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:src="@drawable/read" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/AppLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Write"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AppLogo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/write" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Calendar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Write"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Write"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/calendar/>
```

`

Comment: Is R.id.Calendar an ImageButton or a Button?

Comment: please add your layout.xml

Comment: R.id.Calendar is an ImageButton.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have used the `<ImageButton>` tag instead of `<Button>` tag in your layout resource file.
That could be the cause of the error.

Comment: Layout resource file looks ok as well

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Calendar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Read"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

Comment: post your complete layout xml

Comment: added the full layout xml

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
ImageButton Calendar = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.Calendar);
```

To:

```
Button Calendar = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Calendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an Eclipse problem not in your code.
Solution for this is just copy your code in `xml`  by Ctrl+c and save the `xml` then again paste it again then save it and run.....this works with me.